# The Server Instance cannot be started because the IntegratedWebLogicServer Domain was not built successfully

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, setup-project, jdeveloper

I am new to ADF.In JDeveloper, I tried to run my first project , It asked for a password for the first time, after entering this, it should run my project but it gave the below error-
`The Server Instance cannot be started because the IntegratedWebLogicServer Domain was not built successfully.`

For more information,
There was a log file too.

```
Adding environment variable to WLST script USER_MEM_ARGS = -Xms32m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
Log File:      C:\Users\absasahu\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain.log
Label:         JDEVADF_PT.12.2.1.4.0_GENERIC_190911.2248.S
Product Home:  C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\jdeveloper\jdev\
Domain:        C:\Users\absasahu\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\DefaultDomain

BuildDefaultDomain1.py      2022-05-18 07:55:17

cmd.exe /c ""C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\oracle_common\common\bin\wlst.cmd" "C:\Users\absasahu\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.4.42.190911.2248\o.j2ee.adrs\BuildDefaultDomain1.py""
Process started
wlst > \Java\jdk1.8.0_331 was unexpected at this time.
Elapsed time:  395 ms
```

Please help me out.

What I tried-

1. Set java_home system variable without any whitespaces.(Not worked).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , Solved my problem.
Go through this link [http://dstas.blogspot.com/2012/09/integrated-weblogic-domain-creation.html][1]

Solution 1- Set environment variables JAVA_HOME , and value as path to your jdk. But keep in mind to shorten(remove whitespaces) like use `PROGRA~2` for `program files(*86)`.

Solution 2- If you have more than One java path set on environment variables, remove them.
It will work now. It worked for me too.